# ASP.NET Core 3.0 disposing controllers and services

Tags: asp.net-core

Back in the days, people used to dispose controllers which were inheriting `Controller` class. Is it still a good practice to manually dispose `ApplicationDbContext` in controllers/services, since the DI library handles the disposal? We only have to register our context handle.

```
services.AddDbContext<SaveBeesContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Example code:

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IAuthService _authService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public AuthController(IAuthService authService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _authService = authService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // ...

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _authService.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Test.Services
{
    public interface IAuthService : IDisposable
    {
        // ...
    }

    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AuthService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // ...

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, never seen IDisposable manually implemented like this in ASP.NET, not in any books, nor in example projects like this https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

Comment: I don't see ApplicationDbContext there. Look code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. It implements IDisposable.

Comment: It just adds additional code with no useful purpose.